# Python list operations with elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I was trying to operate with a list and a loop. The thing is that I have a list like the following a = [9, 3, 5, 2] and I want to subtract 1 to each element... So I have tried something like this

```
a = [9, 3, 5, 2]
b = -1
x = a - b
```

Answer (score 2):

Somewhat beyond the scope of your actual question but you could use some magic functions to abstract away the details:

```
class MyCoolList(list):
    def __sub__(self, other):
        return [item - other for item in self]

    def __add__(self, other):
        return [item + other for item in self]

    def __mul__(self, other):
        return [item * other for item in self]
```

Now we can do:

```
cls = MyCoolList([9, 3, 5, 2])

print(cls - 1)
print(cls + 1)
print(cls * 2)
```

Which yields

```
[8, 2, 4, 1]
[10, 4, 6, 3]
[18, 6, 10, 4]
```

---

To not repeat yourself (`DRY`), you may very well use the `operator` module:

```
import operator as op


class MyCoolList(list):
    def calc(self, what, other):
        return [what(item, other) for item in self]

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return self.calc(op.sub, other)

    def __add__(self, other):
        return self.calc(op.add, other)

    def __mul__(self, other):
        return self.calc(op.mul, other)
```

---

In the end, you could use a decorator altogether:

```
import operator as op

def calc(operator_function):
    def real_decorator(function):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            lst, other = args
            return [operator_function(item, other) for item in lst]

        return wrapper

    return real_decorator


class MyCoolList(list):

    @calc(op.sub)
    def __sub__(self, other):
        pass

    @calc(op.add)
    def __add__(self, other):
        pass

    @calc(op.mul)
    def __mul__(self, other):
        pass


cls = MyCoolList([9, 3, 5, 2])
print(cls - 1)
print(cls + 1)
```

Comment: I was trying to improve this as you said it is repetitive. Your last edit is what I end up with :) Nice!

Comment: However, I'm still looking for ways to improve it because `__sub__` uses `op.sub`, `__add__` uses `op.add`... So it's still repetitive in some context :)

Comment: @Asocia: It is repetitve, indeed. Maybe with some sort of decorator.

Comment: @Asocia: Added a decorator variant. Maybe it's useful for someone.

Answer (score 1):

use list comprehension

```
a = [9, 3, 5, 2]
b = [x-1 for x in a]
```

output:

```
[8, 2, 4, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple one liner using `lambda` and `map`

```
a = [9, 3, 5, 2]
x = list(map(lambda i: i-1, a))
print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to python here is the simplest one

```
a = [9, 3, 5, 2]
b=[]
for i in a:
    b.append(i-1)
print(b)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[8, 2, 4, 1]
```